# Max value for each cell

Tags: arcmap, raster-calculator

I am using ArcMap. I have 12 raster layers with coincident pixels, which have different values. I would like to, for each pixel location, pick the pixel from all 12 rasters which have the same value.

I imagine I need to use raster calculator for this, but I am really not sure where to start.

Comment: Perhaps use the 'Cell Statistics' tool (spatial analyst required) with the 'Maximum' statistic_type. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm

Comment: do you need to know which raster in the stack the max value comes from or just the maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Mosaic Dataset, import the rasters and set [mosaic operator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/mosaic-operators.htm#GUID-16A8936C-9248-4211-95DA-7A47706C99B5) to max to get max pixel value for overlapping rasters.

> A mosaic dataset allows you to store, manage, view, and query small to
>   vast collections of raster and image data. It is a data model within
>   the geodatabase used to manage a collection of raster datasets
>   (images) stored as a catalog and viewed as a mosaicked image.

See [What is a Mosaic dataset?](http://What%20is%20a%20mosaic%20dataset?)

[image]